# How to replace one String with another in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, replace

I have a column named Date with 100 rows in my SQlite Database. It is in the format 12-31-2012 16:34:17 p.m.

I need to replace that with 12-31-2012 16:34:17 pm How to acheive this ?

I have thought of update command but im confused how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace p.m. by pm in rows containing dates ending with p.m.

```
UPDATE <tablename>
   SET Date=REPLACE(Date, 'p.m.', 'pm')
```

**Not Tested**

Comment: There are 100 rows, i need change that for all the rows.

Comment: This will update all rows that have the Date containing p.m

Comment: How will it update other rows ? They will have different date and time

Comment: Tried WHERE Date LIKE '%p.m.'  WHERE Date LIKE 'p.m.%'  WHERE Date LIKE '%p.m.%'   None of them worked.

Comment: I have removed the LIKE now as p.m. is unlikely in any other context in a column named DATE. Also consider saving dates in this format (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for date based queries from within SQLITE.

Answer (score 0):

in php.....

```
<?php
$dbhandle = sqlite_open('sqlitedb');
$query = sqlite_query($dbhandle, 'SELECT primarykeyid, Date FROM table');
while ($row = sqlite_fetch_array($query, SQLITE_ASSOC)) {
    if ((substr($row['Date'], -4) == 'p.m.') {
        $datestringtoupdate = substr($row['Date'], 0, -4).'pm';
    } else {
        $datestringtoupdate = substr($row['Date'], 0, -4).'am';
    }
    $update = sqlite_query($dbhandle, "UPDATE table SET Date='$datestringtoupdate' WHERE primarykeyid=$row[primarykeyid]");
}
?>
```